# Installing mongodb php7 extension version 1.5.0 in ubuntu server

Tags: apt, php, mongodb

I installed mongodb php extension using `apt-get install php7.0-mongodb`

when I check, it shows that the installed version is 1.2.0, But, I want to install version 1.5.0

So, I tried `apt-get install php7.0-mongodb=1.5.0`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.5.0' for 'php7.0-mongodb' was not found
```

how can I install version 1.5.0?

I am using ubuntu 16, php7.0

Answer (score 3):

To get the newest version of php-mongodb you need to install it using perc.

1. `sudo apt install php-pear` (this will install perc)
2. `sudo apt install php-dev`
3. `sudo pecl install mongodb`

After executing these commands you should have the newest available mongodb extension installed on your system.

4. The last step of installation the **extension** is to add `extension=mongodb.so` to `php.ini` files. You should find this files in `/etc/php/7.2/cli/` and `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/ folders`. Find sections with extensions list and put it under it. Change both files.

Now you should **install the library**, using composer.
In your project type:

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

The reason behind installing **extension and library** is explained in the official mongodb docs here https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/.

That's all!

Comment: If `sudo apt install php-dev` gives you a not found, run `sudo apt-get update` and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no package named[`php7.0-mongodb`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=php7.0-mongodb).

But [`php-mongodb`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=php-mongodb&searchon=names) exists.
You will get version 1.1.5-1~build1 on 16.04 LTS and  1.3.4-1build1 on 18.04 LTS.

So the correct command would be:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

Comment: when I `apt-get install php7.0-mongodb` in my machine. It said:
`php7.0-mongodb is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.`
phpinfo shows the version is 1.2.0
But I want to install the version 1.4.0.
`apt-get install php7.0-mongodb=1.4.0` gave me:
`Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.4.0' for 'php7.0-mongodb' was not found`

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, I got fixed with this.

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
sudo apt-get install php-dev
sudo apt-get install mongodb

sudo phpenmod mongodb
```